# move forwad and backword in listview (window explorer of computer) using stack

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, stack

i have the code in which i m displaying directories and files from the computer.i can open them by using folerbrowser. so far so good but now i want to add backward and forward button so that i can see the previous folder or file selected and go fwd to.

```
    public partial class ListView : Form
    {

        public ListView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;

        }

        private void PopulateListView()
        {
            listView1.Clear();
            //headers listview

            listView1.Columns.Add("File Name", 200);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Size", 80);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Last Accessed", 110);
            ExtensionsHolder.Clear();
            if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //int thefile = 0;
                string[] dirData = new string[3];
                string[] filData = new string[3];
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowser.SelectedPath);
                var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowser.SelectedPath)
     .Where(d => !new DirectoryInfo(d).Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System | FileAttributes.Hidden));


                try
                {
                //THIS IS THE ITERATION TO GET SUBDIRECTORIES
                foreach (string dir in folders)
                {
                    //string name = Path.g;
                    dirData[0] = dir.ToString();
                    dirData[1] = dir.Length.ToString();
                    dirData[2] = File.GetLastAccessTime(dir).ToString();
                    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(dirData, imageList1.Images.Count);
                    lv.Tag = dir;

                    imageList1.Images.Add(IconExtractor.Form1.GetFolderIcon(IconExtractor.IconSize.Small, IconExtractor.FolderType.Closed));

                    listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;
                    listView1.Items.Add(lv);

                }
                //THIS IS ITERATION FOR FILES OF THE DIRECTORY

                    foreach (string file in files)
                    {

                        FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(file);
                        FileAttributes fatr = finfo.Attributes;

                        string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                        filData[0] = name;
                        filData[1] = finfo.Length.ToString();
                        filData[2] = File.GetLastAccessTime(file).ToString();
                        ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(filData, imageList1.Images.Count - 1);
                        lv.Tag = file;
                        string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
                        if (!extension.Equals("") && !ExtensionsHolder.Contains(extension))
                        {
                            ExtensionsHolder.Add(extension);
                            imageList1.Images.Add(BlackFox.Win32.Icons.IconFromExtensionShell(extension, BlackFox.Win32.Icons.SystemIconSize.Small));
                        }

                        listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

                        listView1.Items.Add(lv);

                    }
                }
                 catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
               listView1.Items.Add("Access denied");
            } 

            }
        }
        List<string> ExtensionsHolder = new List<string>();
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string chattextbox=textBox1.Text;
}
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




            PopulateListView();
            textBox1.Text = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
        }

        private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                try
                {
                    string sPath = listView1.FocusedItem.Tag.ToString();

                     Process.Start(sPath);
        }
        catch(Exception Exc)    {   MessageBox.Show(Exc.ToString());    }    
    }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
         listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
            if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex==1)
                listView1.View = View.SmallIcon;
            if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex==2)
                listView1.View = View.Details;
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
                listView1.View = View.List;
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 5)
                listView1.View = View.Tile;



        }

        private void Farward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Stack fpath = new Stack();
            Stack<string> itemindex = new Stack<string>();
            itemindex.Push(listView1.SelectedIndices.ToString());
            itemindex.Push("two");
            itemindex.Push("three");
            //itemindex.Push("four");
            //itemindex.Push("five");

            // A stack can be enumerated without disturbing its contents. 
            foreach (string number in itemindex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nPopping '{0}'", itemindex.Pop());
            Console.WriteLine("Peek at next item to destack: {0}",
                itemindex.Peek());
            Console.WriteLine("Popping '{0}'", itemindex.Pop());
        }

        private void Back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                    if (i != 0)
                    {
                        listView1.Items[i - 1].SubItems[1].Text = "Selected";
                        // txtPath.Text = listView1.Items[i - 1].Text;

                }

            }
        }

        private void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("selected index"+ listView1.SelectedIndices[0]);
            else
            MessageBox.Show("No item selected");
        }


    }
}
```

Forward . . .

```
private void Farward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Stack fpath = new Stack();
    Stack<string> itemindex = new Stack<string>();
    itemindex.Push(listView1.SelectedIndices.ToString());
    itemindex.Push("two");
    itemindex.Push("three");
    //itemindex.Push("four");
    //itemindex.Push("five");

    // A stack can be enumerated without disturbing its contents. 
    foreach (string number in itemindex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nPopping '{0}'", itemindex.Pop());
    Console.WriteLine("Peek at next item to destack: {0}",
        itemindex.Peek());
    Console.WriteLine("Popping '{0}'", itemindex.Pop());
}
```

Backward . . .

```
private void Back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
        {
            listView1.Items[i - 1].SubItems[1].Text = "Selected";
            // txtPath.Text = listView1.Items[i - 1].Text;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to break it down dude . . . unless people love you, no one is actually going to find the error for you.  Show us the snippets that you think are the causes of your error and be more descriptive.  If it is too abstract/conceptual you run the risk of the question being closed.

Comment: there is no error in my code i want to get the backword and forward button working ....for tat i need to get the selecteditems in an array and the get when back buton is clicked it go to the previous file open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of hard to do this because your code contains a lot of unecessary UI stuff.  Anyway this is how I did it . . .

Let `lvItems` be our ListView, and allow `A B C D` be the elements in our ListView.  We select only A, C, D . . .

```
lvItems.SelectedIndices.Add(0);
lvItems.SelectedIndices.Add(2);
lvItems.SelectedIndices.Add(3);
```

So in our `Next` button, we define the Click event as follows . . .

```
Stack<string> sItms = new Stack<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < lvItems.SelectedIndices.Count; ++i)
{
    int idx = lvItems.SelectedIndices[i];
    string itm = lvItems.Items[idx].ToString();
    sItms.Push(itm);
}

// Our set contains D, C, A 
// Peek() will display D
```

And in our `Back` button, we define the Click event as follows . . .

```
Stack<string> sItms = new Stack<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < lvItems.SelectedIndices.Count; ++i)
{
    int idx = lvItems.SelectedIndices[(lvItems.SelectedIndices.Count - 1)-i];
    string itm = lvItems.Items[idx].ToString();
    sItms.Push(itm);
}

// Our Set Contains A, C, D
// Peek() will display A
```

Is this what you're looking for?  Tell me how it goes . . .

Comment: oke let me try it then will tell u..actually what i wanted to do was that when mouse double click event occurs ...it gets saved in the stack...and when i click back it moves back to the previous click then the prvious and so on....now what i can do is add the event clicks in the stack being defined in the button click and then call that method in fwd and bck buton